# C# Поиск максимума/минимума в IEnumerable

Tags: c#, массивы, linq, коллекции, поиск

Вопрос следующий - как работает Max/Min в Linq? То есть, мы ведь не можем вытащить первый элемент по индексу из коллекции(т.к индексирование в коллекции не реализовано) и присвоить его в нашу переменную, а потом, пробегая по циклу, сравнивать её. Очевидно, что можно сделать это через перегонку коллекции в тот же массив, но есть ли другой способ? Без создания массива/листа и пробега уже по нему?

Comment: "без создания массива/листа и пробега уже по нему" - есть, можно посмотреть в исходном коде [Enumerable.Max](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Max.cs,df1591e64f4cee3a,references) (это для double), а [это](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Max.cs,121902bcb741dfe1,references) обобщенно

Comment: А зачем по индексу, если первый элемент просто берётся и всё. И следом по очереди берутся остальные и сравниваются.

Comment: Не понял вопроса, зачем это делать? Есть же стандартные методы.

Comment: @aepot просто хотелось узнать, как это работает изнутри

Comment: @Aarnihauta огромное спасибо за ссылочки - очень полезная вещь; вопрос решён

Comment: @Iceneo - я Вам из своего пыта советую: реализуйте какую нибудь свою собственную Linq - коллекцуию, а потом попоробуйте её повызывать в разных запросах... Это может сильно помочь в понимании

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден - можно организовать метод расширения и вызвать enumerator.MoveNext(), если вернёт false, то дропаем exception, иначе присваиваем enumerator.Current. Позже, пробегаем по всей коллекции, используя всё тот же MoveNext() и сравниваем.

```
public static class IEnumerableExtension
    {
        public static T MyMax<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) 
            where T : IComparable
        {
            var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            var max = enumerator.Current;
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                max = max.CompareTo(enumerator.Current) < 0 ? enumerator.Current : max;
            return max;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Извините, а вот прямо даже интересно стало... А можете дополнить ответ строчками кода? Просто так понятнее будет...

Comment: `exception` зачем, если можно прервать выполнение цикла командой `break;`?

Comment: @aepot exception чтоб неповадно было

Comment: @S.H. `while (enumerable.MoveNext()) Console.WriteLine(enumerable.Current);`

Comment: @S.H. дополнил сообщение

Comment: @aepot я сторонник того, что если уж коллекция пустая, то пусть пользователю дадут об этом знать, чем просто прокнет break, или же, присвоится default

Comment: ок, хороший код, только мне кажется, что тернарный оператор здесь лишний, достаточно было простого `if`, ведь альтернативная ветка не нужна. Нет смысла присваивать `max` в `max`. Второе вот здесь `var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();` надо `using` добавить, так как любой энумератор `IDisposable`, особенно это критично, если в `max` попадет `null` и будет выброшено досрочное исключение, а энумератор может ведь и файл итерировать и вообще что угодно. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Max.cs